# Adding custom version for C/C++ code file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My question is related to C source files.
Let me try and explain in simple terms.
Let's say I've 2 executables as below -

- `main1.exe` - created by linking `main1.c`, `f1.c`, `f2.c`
- `main2.exe` - created by linking `main2.c`, `f2.c`, `f3.c`

I need to mark these code files with some custom text so that I can identify the version of code used to build the executable.
For example, I change `f2.c` and limit compilation to just creation of `main1.exe`

So on the basis of some custom text, I would like to identify that `main1.exe` contains changed version of `f2.c` whereas `main2.exe` doesn't.
Basically, a `grep` command like below should confirm that `main1.exe` has custom text and `main2.exe` doesn't.

```bash
grep <custom text> *.exe
```

Is there any directive/macro which can be defined to achieve this?

Alternatively, I can simply add a comment `/* f2.c_version_xxx */` and `grep` this text.
However, I wanted to check if C provides any feature that can be used to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Did you try defining the "file version" in a static string at the top of the file?

Comment: Why tag both languages? They are not the same.

Comment: This is an XY problem. The real solution is to use a Makefile. This is what they're for.

Comment: Long time ago rcs and ident provided a way to identify each source file/version within the builded executable by means of static version string.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you want an aid for building executable linking up to date libraries (use build tools like MAKE) or implement something like https://wandbox.org/permlink/sPLrnk2ml6Ody5Pk

Comment: You want to _identify_ the version of code used to build the executable __or__ you want to recompile all dependents when dependency changes?

Comment: Let me try and explain in a different way. My application has over 3000 C codes & over 110 executables. We are in process of migrating from RHEL6 to RHEL 8/9. I cannot migrate all 110 executables in one go. It needs to be done in phase-wise manner. Let's say I've a c-function which for example fetches value for a variable from environment. This c-function would be used in most of 110+ executables in the application. << continued in next comment >>

Comment: I change it but I suppress compilation of 110+ executables (there's a way I can suppress) and create only few executables which I can test and release (in RHEL6 environment) at a time. After few weeks, I'll have some executables which have modified version of my c-function & some without it. I want to develop a mechanism by which I can identify which executable has which version of code (original of modified). To make things complex, it's not just one c-function. I've over 3000 c-functions to handle. Each executable is built linking 50+ c-functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-D` [preprocessor option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) with two different values:

```bash
$ gcc -c main1.c f1.c f2.c -DBUILD_VERSION=1 -o main1.exe
$ gcc -c main2.c f3.c f2.c -DBUILD_VERSION=2 -o main2.exe
```

`f2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int version = BUILD_VERSION;

void print_build_version()
{
    printf("file version used to build this file is %d\n", version);
}
```

It's also possible to use a const char like this:

`f2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char version_cstr[] = BUILD_VERSION;

void print_build_version()
{
    printf("file version used to build this file is %s\n", version_cstr);
}
```

```bash
$ gcc -c main1.c f1.c f2.c -DBUILDSTR="\"Build version 1\"" -o main1.exe
```

Because `version_cstr` is a const variable, its content should be placed inside the read only section, you can use `objdump` to find the the value of `version_cstr` before execution:

```bash
$ objdump -sj .rdata f2.o
```

Comment: How about `#define BUILD_VERSION_STR #BUILD_VERSION`, so that you don't need to use quotes: `-DBUILD_VERSION=1.3.5`

Comment: Yes probably better, thanks for pointing out !

Answer (score 0):

When you want to recompile all dependents of a source file, you should use a build system. That's what they are for. Consider using CMake instead of a Makefile or IDE.

> mark these code files with some custom text so that I can identify the version of code used to build the executable

Great. Generate a version, for example md5 sum, of each source file and embed that into the executable. There is nothing such available with "c-preprocessor" or in C, that you tagged your question with.

*On Linux with CMake* I could consider generating a text file containing all md5sums and filenames of all files used in compilation and add that to a new section inside the executable. Something along the following could get you started:

```
get_target_property(srcs my_project SOURCES)
add_custom_command( 
   OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_projects.md5
   DEPENDS ${srcs}
   COMMAND md5sum ${srcs} > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_projects.md5
)
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_project_with_versions
   DEPENDS my_project ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_projects.md5
   COMMAND objcopy
      --add-section myversions=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_projects.md5
      --set-section-flags .mydata=noload,readonly
      $<TARGET_FILE:my_project>
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_project_with_versions
)
```